# Difference between Single Sign-Out and Single Log-Out

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Is there a difference in the concept? I've seen separate code for both but have been unable to find any answers online regarding the differences between the two.

Comment: they are different. SLO is more complicated. you must read the official SAML profile document to understand it with the official standard. `4.4 Single Logout Profile` and `4.1 Web Browser SSO Profile` . https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The SAML v2.0 specification defines the single logout profile. This involves the transmission of SAML logout requests and logout responses between the identity provider and service provider(s). I think you'll find that single sign-out is synonymous with single logout.

Comment: The SAMLServiceProviderSAMLServiceProvider in from the ComponentSpace.SAML2 dll has two separate functions: ReceiveSLO and ReceiveSSO. This leads me to beleive there are some kind of differences. I'm going to read more into this.

Comment: ReceiveSSO supports SAML sign-on (ie SSO). ReceiveSLO supports SAML logout (ie SLO aka sign-out).